# Hpricot is parsing an xml file incorrectly: misreads empty tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, hpricot

I have an xml file whose contents are thus:

```
<data>
  <title/>
  <creator/>
  <copyright>Foo</copyright>
</data>
```

There's no doctype, which might be related to the problem.  I'm reading it in with the Hpricot gem (0.8.1), in rails 2.2.2.  When it parses it, it doesn't treat the `title` tag as empty, and instead wraps it around its sibling tags:

```
doc = Hpricot(File.read("#{ENV['HOME']}/test.xml")) 
=> #<Hpricot::Doc {elem <data> "\n  " {elem <title> "\n  " {emptyelem <creator>} "\n  " {elem <copyright> "Foo" </copyright>} "\n"} </data>} "\n">

puts doc.to_s
<data>
  <title>
  <creator />
  <copyright>Foo</copyright>
</title></data>
```

Can anyone explain what's going wrong?  I don't see why the `title` tag would be treated differently to the `creator` tag: if there is an issue with not having doctype for example then i'd think these two tags would both suffer from it (or neither of them).

Comment: Hpricot is exactly parsing what you are asking it to do. `creator` is the empty tag here and it is followed by `copyright`. Both of these are nested inside `title` tag. Although `title` is never really closed but as per the heirarchy it makes sesne what Hpricot is doing.

Comment: But `creator` is not nested inside `title` tag in my orignal xml file: `title` is an empty tag just like `creator`.